# Please help me block this traffic

Tags: networking, server, iptables

I have been trying to disable this functionality for quite some time, but cannot seem to figure it out.

Within a 1 minute interval several packet sniffer tools report constant traffic from all-systems.mcast.net with a set size of 14 bytes.

[image: Traffic]

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ netstat -g
IPv6/IPv4 Group Assignments
interface   RefZäh Group
--------------- ------ ---------------------
lo              1      all-systems.mcast.net
eth0            1      all-systems.mcast.net
lo              1      ip6-allnodes
lo              1      ff01::1
eth0            1      ff02::1:ff84:d990
eth0            1      ip6-allnodes
eth0            1      ff01::1
```

It's designated IP is 224.0.0.1

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ netstat -ng
IPv6/IPv4 Group Assignments
interface   RefZäh Group
--------------- ------ ---------------------
lo              1      224.0.0.1
eth0            1      224.0.0.1
lo              1      ff02::1
lo              1      ff01::1
eth0            1      ff02::1:ff84:d990
eth0            1      ff02::1
eth0            1      ff01::1
```

I have already managed to stop other multicast packets, namely traffic from 224.0.0.251, using this:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 -multicast
```

However, this has not stopped the all-systems.mcast.net traffic.

I have also unsuccessfully tried iptables, inspired by a website regarding the opposite of what I am trying to do: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8286

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 224.0.0.0/4 -j REJECT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j REJECT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 240.0.0.0/5 -j REJECT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j REJECT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -j REJECT
```

Does anyone know how to stop this 224.0.0.1 / all-systems.mcast.net traffic?

Comment: It looks like you only blocked incoming requests, but not outgoing ones. The `=>` in your screenshot implies that the traffic is outgoing from 192.168.0.1 to the Multicast address. Try adding an iptables rule for the `OUTPUT` chain as well.

Comment: 224.0.0.0 is multicast.

Comment: @Oldskool:  I have tried adding the same for the OUTPUT chain, but I am still sending 12 bytes every minute to all-systems.mcast.net. netstat -g shows all-systems.mcast.net to correspond with etho and lo. I have already been able to block traffic from 224.0.0.251 with ifconfig eth0 -multicast. There must be a similar way to block the 224.0.0.1 aka all-systems.mcast.net.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Record all traffic with a screenshot/video for one hour

step 2. Shutdown NIC, Router or Modem. (disable internet line temporary)

Step 3. Analyze  footage, log all IP addresses.

Step 4. Verify YOUR IP's

Step 5. Use an IP Whitelist or another type of filter to block invalid IP addresses.(document which IP's)

Step 6. Reboot all systems.(computer, router, modem)

Step 7. Test it

Hope this helps :)